# Is there any way to have an Adobe PDF Fragment accept parameters to change its behavior?

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, fragment, subform

I'm looking to create an adobe pdf fragment (footer) with a name, address, and phone number. However, some documents require a different phone number for international usage. Instead of creating 2 fragments and using a Choice subform, I was hoping there was a way to create a single fragment that had the phone number dynamically generate based on some property.

Is there any way to do what I'm thinking, or do I have to stick with 2 separate fragments + a choice subform?

---

Further clarification:

My thought is this... if I can have the fragment use script to dynamically set the text of the phone number field, that would be great. The forms themselves would set some sort of variable or custom property or something that the fragment could use in its script.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "(...) phone number dynamically generate based on some property". Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden checkbox in the main form with an appropriate value and access it from the "form fragment" using adobe javascript.